# Babel.js method decorators applying to class instead of method

Tags: javascript, decorator, babeljs

While attempting to apply a decorator to a class' method, It's seemingly applying it to the class instead. Me, being not all that familiar with decorators/annotations, It's more than likely user-error.

Here's a really quick example that I've whipped up:

```
class Decorators {
    static x (y, z) {
        return method => {
            // do stuff with y, z, method
            // method should be the method that I decorate
        }
    }
}

class Foo {
    @Decorators.x('foo', 'bar')
    static main () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, inside of the decorator, the method should be equal to the `static main` method, but when I add a `console.log` to the decorator to see what the method is, it logs `[Function: Foo]` (which is the Foo class after transpilation via Babel)...

From what I can tell, Babel.js is applying the decorator to the class, even though it's set on the method. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Not related to your question, just wanted to comment that it seems strange to make `Decorators` a class if it is only going to be a bag of functions. Might as well use an object literal.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah, I would agree, but it's the closest example to the code that I'm working on, which makes loads more sense than just what you see in the Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter is the `target` (it can be the class constructor - for statics, the prototype - for non-statics, and the instance, in case of properties). And the second one is the method's name:

```
return (target, name, descriptor) => {
  console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Can you link to any documentation that says this?

Comment: "instance of the class" isn't quite right, it's just known as the `target`. In the case of statics it is the class constructor, in the case of non-statics, is the prototype, and in the case of class props, is the instance.